# New Urls patterns and multiple variables with the same name

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm using Django 2.0 type of urls, and I have urls with multiple variables in them, with the same name. I'm using also ClassBasedView

```
path('/companies/<int:pk>/products/<int:pk>/', AccountCompanyProductDetailView.as_view()
```

I'm using pk because is the primary key and CBV will know how to use it (similar for other Model fields).

If I use other names, CBV will not know what to search.

In a CBV how can I get the parameters and know which is which. ?
How Django knows pk from which Model I need in each position ?

Comment: I dont think so....I think it is better to use different name for different vars

Comment: Are you asking how to access the parameters in your CBV? I would rename them to ``<int:myparam1>`` and ``<int:myparam2>`` and access them in my class.

Comment: but If I don't use pk (primary key) or slug, how a CBV will search, if is not the name of the field I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not know how to handle this. You need to rename your parameters and access them in your `CBV`.
This could look like the following:

`urls.py`:

```
path('/companies/<int:pk1>/products/<int:pk2>/', AccountCompanyProductDetailView.as_view())
```

`views.py`:

```
class AccountCompanyProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product

    def get_object(self):
        pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
        pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
        company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk1)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk2)
        return product
```

You would need to do this in other views too. Override the according methods like [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset). Access the `kwargs` as shown above.

Comment: That code should probably be in `get_queryset` or `get_objectz, but otherwise yes.